# Proxied HTTP/2 Apple APN connection with Jetty HttpClient 9.3.6.v20151106

Tags: java, jetty, http-proxy, http2

I'm trying to send a push notification through the new Apple APN HTTP/2 interface, using an authenticated HTTP proxy (like Squid).

Using Jetty HTTPClient 9.3.6.v20151106 I've managed to send a notification without using proxy, following the code on [this page](http://judepereira.com/blog/sending-notifications-via-apples-new-http2-api-using-jetty-9-3-6/).

Apple APN HTTP/2 API requires ALPN TLS extension. I'm using JavaSE 1.8.0_u40, so I have modified the JVM bootclasspath with alpn-boot-8.1.3.v20150130.jar:

```
-Xbootclasspath/p:/latinia/dev/LIMSP/Collectors/AppleHTTP2/alpn-boot-8.1.3.v20150130.jar
```

Now I'm trying to establish a TLS tunnel through a Squid proxy server. Attending to Jetty documentation, the proxy is configured like this:

```
        HttpProxy httpProxy = new HttpProxy("proxyHost", 3128);
        ProxyConfiguration proxyConfig = client.getProxyConfiguration();
        proxyConfig.getProxies().add(httpProxy);
```

When I run my code with proxy set, ALPN API is throwing an internal exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1011)
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1006)
at org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.ALPN.put(ALPN.java:149)
at org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.client.ALPNClientConnection.<init>(ALPNClientConnection.java:44)
at org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.client.ALPNClientConnectionFactory.newConnection(ALPNClientConnectionFactory.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.client.http.HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2.newConnection(HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2.java:150)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpProxy$HttpProxyClientConnectionFactory.newConnection(HttpProxy.java:84)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.client.http.HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2.lambda$doStart$0(HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2.java:80)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.client.http.HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2$$Lambda$2/1340328248.newConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.client.HTTP2Client$ClientSelectorManager.newConnection(HTTP2Client.java:334)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.createEndPoint(ManagedSelector.java:411)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.access$1600(ManagedSelector.java:56)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CreateEndPoint.run(ManagedSelector.java:587)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.execute(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:101)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.run(ManagedSelector.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I don't have a clue on whats going on ¿Has anyone succeeded at doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Jetty 9.3.8 fixes a number of bugs related to forward proxy handling, like your example. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you can't for this version.

The version 9.3.8 resolves your NPE exception.

However, the HttpProxy uses the HttpClient which uses only one transportClient. When you try to communicate with your proxy, it uses HTTP/2 (PRI * HTTP/2.0) instead of HTTP/1.1.

I'm working on transportClient, which can use http 1.1 or http 2. The choice depend on ALPN negotiation. I'm trying to integrate the proxy.

https://github.com/stephanemartin/jettyTests/tree/master/src/main/java/testjettys2

Bug: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/250